# 3rd party cookie in safari does not persist in iframe itself

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, safari

I've got a page with a small ecommerce/basket/checkout flow. Which relies on a basket_id stored in a cookie.

This page is being included via an iframe on several different domains. In all browsers the checkout flow works, except for safari.

After researching the reason behind this, and why it miracally disappeared (I visited the iframe-domain directly) I found out that third party cookies for domains you've never visited before are being discarded after a page-move.

I found several solutions dating back tot 2012; but most of them are already obsolete by new versions of safari. So I was wondering what *the* way to solve this would be in 2019.

The iframe itself is constructed dynamically, so I could alter this logic a bit to circumvent this problem.

E.g. would it make a difference if, before the creation of the iframe I would visit the domain via an ajax request? Or would that also be a 3rd party cookie then?

or?